# Nginx-rtmp module and mpeg-dash(Dash industry dash.js)

Tags: nginx, video-streaming, rtmp, mpeg-dash, dash.js

## Mpeg Dash-Streaming

I am working in my thesis about live-streaming . I used ffmpeg,ngix server with rtmp module and dash.js from [Dash industry](https://github.com/Dash-Industry-Forum/dash.js). I start stream to server by ffmpeg, and play by dash, player runned well, but there were some problems.

Player only play if mpd-dash play list still have chunk t=0, so whenever user request player and *.mpd updated with out chunk t=0 player do not run.

I upload my *.mpd file to [Dash Validator](http://www-itec.uni-klu.ac.at/dash/?page_id=605) and get error: "Schematron validation not successful – DASH is not valid! ". But playist is generate by nginx - rtmp module not me.

After searching some forum i got some information that nginx-rtmp module generate wrong dash play list *.mpd [Nginx rtmp module -bug](https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module/issues/614) , and may be that bug was fixed and merged to master in github (i thought so [Mered - report](https://github.com/sergey-dryabzhinsky/nginx-rtmp-module/pull/48)) . But i tried downloading newest nginx and rtmp module , Player also play incorrect.

If i played with dash.all.js version 2 year ago : video only play good (play to end) if chunk t=0 is exist in play list *.mpd ,or player do not play (play in middle of streaming)
If i played with dash.all.js lasted version : video play and stop playing soon or loop playing.

I really need some help, my deadline is comming.

Here is my nginx config(main config):

```
    rtmp {

    server {
        listen 1935;
        ping 30s;
        notify_method get;
        chunk_size 4000;
        allow play all;

        application myapp {
            live on;
            dash on;
            dash_path /tmp/dash;

            hls on;
            hls_cleanup on;
            hls_sync 100ms;
            hls_fragment 2s;
            hls_path /tmp/hls;

            allow play all;


        }
    }
}
```

> and some others config:

```
location /hls {
        # Serve HLS fragments
        types {
            application/vnd.apple.mpegurl m3u8;
            video/mp2t ts;
        }
        root /tmp;
        add_header Cache-Control no-cache;
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
    }
    location /dash.js {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location /streaminghls {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location /dash {
        # Serve DASH fragments
        root /tmp;
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;            

    }
```

> and in html player :

```
 <script src="dash-old.all.js"></script>

        <script>
            function getUrlVars() {
                var vars = {};
                var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
                    vars[key] = value;
                });
                return vars;
            }
            function startVideo() {
                var vars = getUrlVars(),
                    url = "http://192.168.100.107:80/dash/Screen.mpd",
                    video,
                    context,
                    player;
                if (vars && vars.hasOwnProperty("url")) {
                    url = vars.url;
                }
                video = document.querySelector(".dash-video-player video");
                context = new Dash.di.DashContext();
                player = new MediaPlayer(context);
                player.startup();
                player.attachView(video);
                player.setAutoPlay(true);
                player.attachSource(url);
            }
        </script>
```

> Hls play excellently but not dash. I tried changing dash config in nginx config and C-source of rtmp-module with recompiling but not thing changed.
>
> My mpd play list :

```
    <MPD xmlns="urn:mpeg:dash:schema:mpd:2011" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2011/XMLSchema-instance" type="dynamic" availabilityStartTime="2015-12-17T03:17:07+07:00" availabilityEndTime="2015-12-17T03:18:23+07:00" minimumUpdatePeriod="PT5S" minBufferTime="PT5S" timeShiftBufferDepth="PT0H0M0.00S" suggestedPresentationDelay="PT10S" profiles="urn:hbbtv:dash:profile:isoff-live:2012,urn:mpeg:dash:profile:isoff-live:2011" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:mpeg:DASH:schema:MPD:2011 DASH-MPD.xsd">
<Period start="PT0S" id="dash">
<AdaptationSet id="1" segmentAlignment="true" maxWidth="320" maxHeight="240" maxFrameRate="20">
<Representation id="Screen_H264" mimeType="video/mp4" codecs="avc1.64000c" width="320" height="240" frameRate="20" sar="1:1" startWithSAP="1" bandwidth="192000">
<SegmentTemplate presentationTimeOffset="0" timescale="1000" media="Screen-$Time$.m4v" initialization="Screen-init.m4v">

<SegmentTimeline>
<S t="0" d="12500"/>
<S t="12500" d="12500"/>
<S t="25000" d="10550"/>
<S t="35550" d="15700"/>
<S t="51250" d="12500"/>
<S t="63750" d="12500"/>
</SegmentTimeline>
</SegmentTemplate>
</Representation>
</AdaptationSet>
<AdaptationSet id="2" segmentAlignment="true">
<AudioChannelConfiguration schemeIdUri="urn:mpeg:dash:23003:3:audio_channel_configuration:2011" value="1"/>
<Representation id="Screen_AAC" mimeType="audio/mp4" codecs="mp4a.40.2" audioSamplingRate="22050" startWithSAP="1" bandwidth="62000">
<SegmentTemplate presentationTimeOffset="0" timescale="1000" media="Screen-$Time$.m4a" initialization="Screen-init.m4a">
<SegmentTimeline>
<S t="0" d="12500"/>
<S t="12500" d="12500"/>
<S t="25000" d="10550"/>
<S t="35550" d="15700"/>
<S t="51250" d="12500"/>
<S t="63750" d="12500"/>
</SegmentTimeline>
</SegmentTemplate>
</Representation>
</AdaptationSet>
</Period>
</MPD>
```

> I really need help.
>
> Thanks for reading, and am so sorry about my bad english.

Answer (score 10):

While this issue was fixed in nginx-rtmp, it looks like the original repository has become stale - the fix is only available in some forks. Try compiling nginx-rtmp from https://github.com/sergey-dryabzhinsky/nginx-rtmp-module or https://github.com/mattpepin/nginx-rtmp-module - both of which seem to have the commit that fixed it in.